# Regular expression matching pattern for 0 or more occurrences

Tags: regex

I have a string of the format `key: [value1, value2, value3]` where the occurrences of values can be 0, 1, 2 or more than 2

i.e. `key: []` or `key: [value1]` or `key: [value1, value2]` or `key: [value1, value2, value3]`

I am trying to define a regular expression that will give me the key and the zero or more values excluding the ", " as separate tokens from the regular expression. I have been able to separate out and get the key, but am unable to get the values as individual strings. Can someone help me with the regular expression for this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to convert a python dictionary that has list of values per key received by java class to a hashmap of the format <String, ArrayList<Strings>>

Comment: Both Anirudh and Expert Systems have given complete working answers with examples. Is there a way I can accept both the answers?  In this case both are independent and correct answers

Comment: It wouldn't let me edit previous comment because 5 minutes had passed, so new comment here.

Both Anirudh and Expert Systems have given complete working answers with examples. Is there a way I can accept both the answers? In this case both are independent and correct answers for the regular expression, which was my question.  But if I have to choose only one, Anirudh has given complete end-to-end answer.

Comment: @adbdkb: Unfortunately, you cannot mark more than one answer as "accepted". Since people facing a similar problem in the future might land on this page looking for an answer (and since there are valid answers available), please mark one of them as "accepted" to make it easy for others to spot it (without having to read through comments etc). (I don't say you should choose mine, just choose the one **you** think provides a more cleanly or thorough solution to the problem at hand.) :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem - I marked Anirudh's answer as accepted answer because it had complete code needed for my set-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use this regex

```
(\\w+):\\s*\\[(.*?)\\]
```

`Group 1` would contain the key and `group 2` all the values.

Now you need to split `group 2` with `,`

---

In java you could do it this way

1>Create a KeyValue class

```
class KeyValue
{
    public final String key;
    public final List<String> values;
    public KeyValue(final String k,final List<String> val)
   {
        key=k;
        values=val;
   }
}
```

2>Now extract it this way

```
KeyValue kv=null;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):\\s*\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find())
{
    kv=new KeyValue(m.group(1),Arrays.asList(m.group(2).split("\\s*,\\s*")));
}
```

---

Now you have your data in KeyValue object kv

```
kv.key;//key Name
for(String s:kv.values)
{
    s;//key value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in pure-regex style. The simplest way is probably to get 'key' and 'values' (everything inside `[...]`) abd then split the values-string into an array of values.
The following regex could be used:

```
([^\s=:+)\s*:\s*\[([^\]]*)\]

// E.g., in pseudocode:
(key, valuesStr) = match(pattern, originalString);
valuesArr = originalString.split(",\s*");
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/73YZJm)** in PHP (implementation in other languages should be similar).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regular expression to get value inside [] then split the string using ','

- step 1: get value inside [] using regular expression : `\[(.*?)\]`
- step 2: split the string using `','`